# how can I create object of a class in another class

Tags: java

I have a class named user and another class user1. I want to create object of user1 in user class. I just do new User1(). But not working.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. :-)

Comment: To get help please post your code ([MCVE])

Comment: Please add more details. This is how you should be asking a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create, new object without reference should write inside main method

```
package com;
public class User {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new User1();
    }

}


package com;

public class User1 {
    User1(){
        System.out.println("kkk");
    }

}
```